# how to stream data from AWS MSK (kafka) to snowflake using MSK connect

Tags: apache-kafka, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, apache-kafka-connect, aws-msk

I'm trying to set up a MSK connector for snowflake and i could hardly see any documentation on how to do it. Unfortunately AWS support person also referred me to use [snowflake documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/kafka-connector-install.html) page.

By following this i can create an EC2 instance and spinoff connector but i wanted to go on serverless mode and use MSK connectors

I'm having hard time with connector properties for snowflake and aws doesnt provide much information about it

Answer (score 1):

As answered on the plugins page, you'd need to upload the Snowflake ZIP/JAR plugins to S3, where they'd be downloaded prior to the connector starting

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/msk/latest/developerguide/msk-connect-plugins.html

Comment: thanks, i' following the same but stuck with connector configurations.

Comment: Stuck how? The required properties are listed in the page you've linked to

Comment: Seeing below exceptions in cloudwatch : ERROR Uncaught exception in REST call to /connectors (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.errors.ConnectExceptionMapper:61)

 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Last encoded character (before the paddings if any) is a valid base 64 alphabet but not a possible value. Expected the discarded bits to be zero.

Comment: Are you sending a valid JSON object to the REST API? - https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/kafka-connector-install.html#id3